# Update with switch and inner join

Tags: ms-access, join, switch-statement, sql-update

I am given a table for a range of option codes, models and availability from someone else. Currently these are updated by hand in the back-end (I know...) and take a whopping 3 months. I want to automate the process, I tried using CASE WHEN but it seems Access cannot handle it. I ran a query that updated based on one clause and it worked fine, see below. Table 1 is in my db, Table 2 is the data I am given translated in to a usable format. It is just a table with 2 columns; option codes and availability (relevant to a specific model)

```
UPDATE Table1
SET Table1.Availability = 'Y'
WHERE 
(
    SELECT Table1.Availability
    FROM Table1
    INNER JOIN Table2
    ON Table1.Code = Table2.Code
    WHERE Table2.Availability='OPT'
)
```

This works but would require a new query for every availability type. Below is my attempt at updating for each availability type. It says there is a syntax error @ Switch(...

```
UPDATE Table1
SET Table1.Availability = 
Switch(
        Table2.Availability = 'OPT', 'Y',
        Table2.Availability = 'STD', 'S', 
        Table2.Availability = 'DEL', 'N'
    )
FROM Table1
INNER JOIN Table2
ON Table1.Code = Table2.Code
WHERE ModelCode = '1234'
;
```

I'm not sure if I am using switch correctly here, help appreciated. If it isn't clear pretty much what I want is If Table2.Availability = OPT, UPDATE Table1.Availability to 'Y' where Code is the same and Model = specific model

I have to specify a model code as the availability for a given option code (Code) is unique. The data I am given is a mess and it is easiest to sort it in to model specific data.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: What syntax reference are you using & what's your justification that this satisfies it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider the following tested and working syntax:

```
UPDATE Table1
INNER JOIN Table2
ON Table1.Code = Table2.Code
SET Table1.Availability = 
Switch(
        Table2.Availability = 'OPT', 'Y',
        Table2.Availability = 'STD', 'S', 
        Table2.Availability = 'DEL', 'N'
    )
WHERE ModelCode = '1234'
;
```

Comment: Thank you so much, that worked. For some reason I thought the JOIN had to go after SET... Appreciate it a lot.

Comment: Using the Access query builder can help avoid such mistakes. First build the SELECT to get the desired table joins and filter, then click the UPDATE query design button and set the field to update. That's all I did.